# Speeding up loading a model in Keras?

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, keras, keras-2

Is there a way to speed up loading a model in Keras?
I'm using a transfer-learned inception model. 
  It seems to take 13 seconds to load a model from my experiences.

I want to load deploy some models onto smart phones. 
Using **Tensorflow** as backend.

```
start = time.time()
path = r'C:\Users\Moondra\Desktop\2017-12-20_10.hdf5'
labels = os.listdir(r'C:\Users\Moondra\Desktop\FISHES_MAIN')
model = load_model(path)

print(time.time() - start)
```

output

```
12.808000087738037
```

Comment: Which backend are you using?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Tensorflow

Answer (score 2):

I found that calling load_model with compile=False sped it up. My times went down from 12-15 seconds to about 2-3 seconds on average.

```
load_model(path, compile=False)
```

Comment: Hmm but then I have to compile it after loading in order to do anythin with my model, don't I? Thus, there would be no benefit..

Comment: Little addition to my comment: No, there is no compilation necessary if you just want to predict stuff. Hence, this realy saved me a lot of trouble :) +1

Comment: I don't get any speedup with this solution.